To setup common threshold color for multiple queries in Grafana Panel
I am using infinity plugin datasource in Grafana to import Logic monitor(LM) device details to grafana using LM rest api and that is working fine (Note: I used UQL query to transform the JSON data from LM rest api to retrive the data understand by Grafana)
Now I want to setup the threshold color indication if one of the queries met the threshold. I am not using the threshold option we have in the panel, as it will indicates the threshold value met separately for the queries which is not my requirement.
Example scenario: If I am using Grafana to show the health status of 3 devices in Logic Monitor, and I am using 3 queries to show these data and all set, I want to visualize red, even if one of the device goes unhealthy.
I tried setting up the value mapping for all the 3 queries, but I get the values showed separately for each queries as shown in the image.
Result I got so far
My requirement is even if one of the query is unhealthy like in my image, i want it to be displayed all together as unhealthy, overall I want to display only unhealthy in the panel along with the color indication. How it can be achieved, with tranformations or expressions?
[ I am also giving the UQL query I used in the panel:
parse-json | jsonata "$map($$,function($d){ return {'data': $map($d.time,function($t, $ti){ return { 'values': $map($d.dataPoints,function($dp,$dpi){ return {  'timestamp': $t, 'metric': $dp, 'value': ($d.values[$ti])[$dpi] = 'No Data' ? null: ($d.values[$ti])[$dpi]  } })}})}}).data.values" | extend "timestamp"=unixtime_milliseconds_todatetime("timestamp") | extend "value"=tonumber("value")
]
